# asus p8z77-v lx and gtx 970 not working in pci-e 16x

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

Today I got this motherboard cause my old p67 motherboard wouldn't work with msi gaming gtx 970. It showed a black screen and refused to post, like it wasn't even connected with the monitor. This same thing happened with the new motherboard while the gpu was in the pci-e 3.0 slot. It just used the iGPU and gtx 970 wasn't even detected in the device manager. Also, the iGPU couldn't be totally disabled. Gtx 970 is properly connected, fans spin and logo lights up.

Then I put it in the second pci-e slot, which is a pci-e 2.0 at 4x speed. And it worked. Monitor turned on, windows booted without a problem. Restarted and went into bios and saw that the iGPU is disabled (memory frequency was showing n/a, before it was 850mhz).

Also, I already updated it to the latest bios and cleared cmos. I really don't want to use the gpu at 4x.

Comment: Some boards have a BIOS setting to toggle on and off PCIe 3.0, as in to turn a lane into a PCIe 2.0 lane. Try looking for that and see if switching it helps.

Comment: I have a sandy bridge cpu which doesn't support pci-e 3.0, so I can only choose between gen1 and gen2. It's already set to gen2 and I just tried putting the gpu back in that slot. Monitor led is just flashing, as if there's no signal. Also, windows boots but I don't see anything.

Comment: I had a similar sounding issue with SandyBridge-E but just toggling the lane back and forth solved it for me

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean exactly by toggling the lane? I can't even enter the bios with gtx 970 in slot 1, not unless monitor is connected to the iGPU dvi port.

Comment: In my BIOS I have an option called something like "Lane 0 type" or something similar. It can be switched between PCI Gen 2.0 and PCI Gen 3.0, literally changing my PCIe slot closest to the CPU between Gen 2 and 3. I managed to get my card to work by switching this option back and forth.

Comment: I wish that would help. Another thing I noticed is that when the gpu is in the second slot, above the settings for the first slot it says "not present", while now when it's in that slot it says "x0". I just know that not being able to completely disable the iGPU is the reason why this is happening.